# How to change default bind sequence of recycler view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

By default, in Android when we bind `RecyclerView` with 2 columns its row binds data like left image below, but I want to bind like right image. How can I do this?

[image]

Here is my code.

```
public void bindRecyclerView(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.vehicleSearchListRecyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager  layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new VehicleAdapter(data));
}
```

Please help.

Comment: It's difficult to say that you can change the reecyclerview's listing order. But the most practical way to do it is ordering the data in a desired sequence. Do you mind preferring the second option?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Kozmotronik. I have ordered the data in desired sequence and after that bind Recycler View and my problem was solved.